# docker wait in gitlab ci doesn't fail job

Tags: docker, sh, gitlab-ci

I'm using docker in docker in my gitlab ci to run my test env and run tests in it.

In order to wait until all tests are finished I use docker wait.

```
tests:
    image: docker:19-git
    stage: tests
    script:
      - docker-compose -f docker-compose/my_test_env.yml up -d #setting up env
      - docker-compose -f docker-compose/tests.yml up -d #running tests
      - docker wait docker-compose-services_tests_1
```

I need to fail job if there are some problems with tests, but (`docker wait docker-compose-services_tests_1`) prints container exit code and returning this exit code is considered as success operation, so job is considered as passed. `docker wait` doesn't have option not to print exit code.

So I need some sh (not bash) script to run `docker wait` and exit with non 0 exit code if container returns non 0 exit code (to fail the job).

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here

1. Removing the `-d` in the second command `docker-compose -f docker-compose/tests.yml up`, doing this you do not need to use the third step
2. if you really want to run the compose dettached, just add a script that captures the output of docker-compose log and according to the result, take an action, exit 0 or 1

Comment: Thanks. But this partially solves my issue. If tests are failing, docker exits with `exited with code 8`. If tests pass, docker exits with `exited with code 0`. But gitlab-ci job succeedes in both cases. But I need it to fail on `exited with code 8`.